# Не работает keyup на кнопке Backspace в мобильном браузере поля number

Tags: html, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

[вот код](https://jsfiddle.net/AJIEKCEU/baamts37/), нашел баг такого рода, у меня samsung s4, так вот в стандартном браузере, когда в поле количество мест, вводишь цифры, то появляется столько же блоков но с ограничением до 5, а вот если очистить поле, то не удаляются те блоки что появились. Заметил, что при нажатии кнопки Backspace, keyup просто не срабатывает. Почему, кто скажет в чем ошибка?

```
Код выше по ссылке
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй подписаться на элемент так:

```
$(document).on('input paste', '.calculation_form', function(e){
  //console.log('keyup!');
    changeColPalet();
    $('#one_place').prop('checked', false);
  });
});
```

На Galaxy S3 работало

Comment: О, заработало, а как понять input paste что-то я такого метода даже ни где не видел, буду благодарен за ответ

Comment: `input` - срабатывает на любой ввод в поле
`paste` - срабатывает на вставку в поле данных путем CTRL+V, ПКМ+вставить, доки: [ссылка](https://learn.javascript.ru/events-change)

Comment: в мобиле заработало а вот в ie9 перестает работать((( код будит общим как для мобил так и для десктопов, способ интересный но не кроссбраузерный(((

Comment: ну это решение не работает в ie9, тут надо сделать условие на проверку браузера, если браузер IE то стандартный keyUp/keyDown/keyPress вешать. На всех остальных браузерах + мобильных поддержка есть.

Comment: ну это уже я понял, просто так не хочется кучу проверок делать))), не ужели нет чего-нибудь универсально работающего, я просто в шоке что keyup не работает(((

Comment: ну так то эту проверку вынести в глобал и записать переменную типа `window._isIE = true`, и использовать по коду `if (window._isIE)`, нагрузки это никакой не несет, а проверка пишется элементарно, примеров в интернете множество. Тут с этим ничего не сделаешь, все что работает везде, скорее всего не работает в IE < 10-11

Comment: да, беда с этими IE, Спасибо!