# Установить max количество вводимых чисел в input type="number" на JS/jQuery для OS Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

Как установить max количество вводимых чисел в input type="number"?
Вот мой код:

```
if(isMobile.Android()){
    $('#cardNumber').attr('type', 'number').attr('max', '19').attr('min', '15');
    $('#cardCode').attr('type', 'number').attr('max', '3').attr('min', '3');
}
```

Необходимо реализовать невозможность ввести большее количество чисел чем установлено, т.е. не просто вывести сообщение о превышении количества чисел, а именно не дать возможность ввести большее количество чисел чем установлено.

**UPD**

Код необходим только для os android

Сделала так:

```
if(isMobile.Android()){
    $('#cardNumber').attr('type', 'number').attr('max', '19').attr('min', '15');
    $('#cardCode').attr('type', 'number').attr('max', '3').attr('min', '3');

    var cardMax = 4;
    $(document).on('input paste', '#cardCode', function(){
        if ($(this).val().length >= cardMax)
            return false;
    });
}
```

Но код не работает, что не так?

Comment: Повесьте событие `onkeyup` на тот инпут, где надо проверять. В этом событии если длина символов > max, то обрезать последние.......либо `keydown` и тогда если количество символов > max - `return false`

Comment: это решение будет работать на android?

Comment: @MarinaVoronova на мобильных устройствах будут работать события `input` и `paste` http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/505441/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jnhmc4d1/      только раз андройд - сделайте `paste` как написал Василий

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну можно сразу использовать эти события (`input`, `paste`), они только в старых IE не работают, для IE под условием нужно слушать события как раз таки `keyUp`, `keyDown`. Причем событие `input` работает лучше и прямей чем `keyUp`. Сколько же с ними было проблем)

Comment: сделала так https://jsfiddle.net/jnhmc4d1/1/
но не работает...

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев я просто писал пример до того, как про андройд писали)

Comment: сорри, я в функции написала `isMobile.Android`, а в заголовок забыла написать поэтому неочевидно было...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я использую такую конструкцию:

```
<input type="text"
    onKeyDown="if(this.value.length==2) this.value = this.value.slice(0,-1)"
/>
```

> Ограничение в два символа

---

**UPD1**

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="maxlimit" data-max="2"/>
```

JS

```
$('input.maxlimit').keydown(function(){
    var max = $(this).data('max');
    if( this.value.length==max ) this.value = this.value.slice(0,-1)
});
```

*Не проверял, но должно работать, возможны орфографические ошибки*

---

**UPD2**

HTML 5

```
<input type="tel" class="maxlimit" data-max="8" pattern=".{4,}"/>
```

JS

```
$('input.maxlimit').keydown(function(){
    var max = $(this).data('max');
    if( this.value.length==max ) this.value = this.value.slice(0,-1)
});
```

*Не проверял, но должно работать, возможны орфографические ошибки*

Добавление потерна не даст отправить форму, если данные не соответствуют шаблону.
Но это лишь только верхушка айсберга.
Вам, как полагаю, более плотно надо подойти к валидации данных, и ограничение на макс длину/кол-во символом это только начало...

Про валидацию не знаю что и сказать, все зависит от задачи и инструментов, что используете.

Для jQuery можно присматреться в этому [плагину](http://jqueryvalidation.org/minlength-method) (сам не использовал).
В Angular можно вполне обойтись штатными средствами.
Кто то пишет свои решения.
Кому то и второго варианта хватает.

---

**UPD3**
Попробуйте что то вроде:

```
$('input.maxlimit').keydown(function(){
    var max = $(this).data('max');
    var keyCode = event.keyCode;
    if( keyCode!=8 && keyCode!=46 && this.value.length==max ) this.value = this.value.slice(0,-1)
    console.log(keyCode); /// OR alert(keyCode);
});
```

8 - backspace, 46 - delete, как в андроид не знаю.
Отловите нужные коды с помощью консоли или того же алерта.

Comment: а как это в файле js прописать? просто необходимо обращаться к  html из файла со скриптами

Comment: Добавил вариант под UPD

Comment: а этот код применим для указания минимального количества чисел?

Comment: Нет не подойдет. Добавил еще вариант. Уточните что вы хотите сделать и получить. Что должно происходить если вводимое число не укладывается в допустимы рамки?

Comment: валидатор есть. вообще эти поля маскируются плагином maskedinput. но для android не подходит http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/509609/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0-js-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%9E%D0%A1-android

поэтому я для android отключила маскирование и делаю валидацию на max и min количество символов

Comment: `pattern` не подойдет, т.к. его не поддерживают старые версии android

Comment: а если мне нужно установить `min` количество символов, то что тут `this.value.slice(0,-1)` необходимо изменить?

Comment: Ни чего. Этот код читается как: В момент нажатия на клавишу, когда еще не пропечался символ, смотрим на длину поля . Если оно равно 2,  удаляем последний символ. И далее уже при отжатие клавиши печатается наш символ.

Comment: еще заметила. с этим кодом при редактировании (удалении) удаляется сразу 2 последних числа. и если встать в середину поля, то каретка почему-то перескакивает в конец...

Comment: Добавил под UPD3, но придется поиграться.